# Append a value in for-loop

Tags: c++, qt

I have a problem with the append/incrementg of QPolygonF values: I push some points into it, which I get continuously and then send the points over signal to other class.

```
...
QPolygonF points;
for(int i= 0; i< 5; ++i)
{
  double value= finalMat.at<double>(i);
  points.push_back(QPointF((double)i, value));
  //points << QPointF((double)i, value);
}
qDebug()<<"points: " << points;

emit updatePointsSignal(points);
```

This code block above removes the old points after reaching the condition number and sends 5 new points with new index. The output is:

```
points: QPolygonF(0, pointValue) QPolygonF(1, pointValue) QPolygonF(2, pointValue) QPolygonF(3, pointValue) QPolygonF(4, pointValue) QPolygonF(0, newPointValue) QPolygonF(1, newPointValue)...
```

How can I increment my points and send them without deleting the old points, so that the output looks like?

```
 points: QPolygonF(0, pointValue) QPolygonF(1, pointValue) QPolygonF(2, pointValue) QPolygonF(3, pointValue) QPolygonF(4, pointValue) QPolygonF(5, newPointValue) QPolygonF(6, newPointValue) QPolygonF(7, newPointValue) QPolygonF(8, newPointValue)...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program is doing exactly what you are asking it to do!, if you want a continuous increment do the following.

```
QPolygonF points;
static int indx = 0;
for(int i= 0; i< 5; ++i)
{
   double value= finalMat.at<double>(i);
   indx += i;
   points.push_back(QPointF((double)indx, value));
}
qDebug()<<"points: " << points;

emit updatePointsSignal(points);
```

Comment: This loop gives me 
`points:  QPolygonF(QPointF(0, 7.31297) QPointF(1, -33.6313) QPointF(3, -0.125985) QPointF(6, 40.1209) QPointF(10, 51.4032) POINTS:  QPolygonF(QPointF(0, 7.31297) QPointF(1, -33.6313) QPointF(3, -0.125985) QPointF(6, 40.1209) QPointF(10, 51.4032) )` So it does not continue

Comment: It should be  indx++; and not  indx+=i;

Comment: great ... you get it now.